# drupal website admin not working

Tags: drupal

I have deployed a drupal website using `https://github.com/morethanthemes/corporateclean`. I have followed the deployment by the word. Now when I try to access the admin panel, it takes the url as `sitename/admin/node` instead of `sitename/?q=admin/node`.

Comment: Have you enabled clean URL?

Comment: What distro are you using? Is Debian based or CentOS? Or is any [x]AMP?

Answer (score 0):

You should enable clean URL first

From Drupal [docs](https://www.drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls):

> By default, Drupal uses and generates URLs for your site's pages that
>   look like "http://www.example.com/?q=node/83". With so-called clean
>   URLs this would be displayed without the "?q=" as
>   "http://www.example.com/node/83".
>
> **Enabling Clean URLs in Drupal**
>
> The standard Drupal installation contains a sample .htaccess file that
>   supports Clean URLs, so make sure this file exists before enabling
>   Clean URLs. Before copying this file make sure there is a dot , in the
>   .htaccess file's name. It is very important to how Apache works.
>
> In Drupal 7, the installer tests for compatibility with Clean URLs as
>   a part of the installation process. If the environment is tested as
>   compatible with Clean URLs, it will be enabled as part of the
>   installation process and no further action is required to enable Clean
>   URLs.
>
> If you need to enable Clean URLs post installation, Drupal will run
>   the clean URL test automatically when you navigate to the Clean URLs
>   configuration page (Administer > Configuration > Search and metadata >
>   Clean URLs), show the results, and allow you to save configuration.
>
> You can enable or disable it at a later time by following these steps:
>
> Navigate to the Clean URLs configuration page (Administer >
>   Configuration > Search and metadata > Clean URLs) Wait for the
>   automated Clean URLs test to run. Check or uncheck the Enable clean
>   URLs checkbox Click "Save configuration" Even if Clean URLs are
>   successfully enabled at install-time, if you have a dedicated server
>   you may still want to follow the steps (below) to enable the more
>   efficient httpd.conf rewrite method for clean URLs. If you choose to
>   do that, you might want to turn off Clean URLs while you are working
>   on the server.

So in your case as: `sitename/admin/node` instead of `sitename/?q=admin/node`.

When clean URL test fails:

Enable mod_rewrite apache from httpd.conf

1. open httpd.conf
2. find mod_rewrite
3. just remove # to enable
4. once it enable then you can run Clean URL
5. this will show check box tick on it and save it

Comment: I tried that...it says that clean URLs are enabled but the clean URL test failed. How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

The standard Drupal installation contains a sample .htaccess file that supports Clean URLs, so make sure this file exists before enabling Clean URLs. Before copying this file make sure there is a dot , in the .htaccess file's name. It is very important to how Apache works

https://www.drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls